# LibGdx collision (wall)

Tags: libgdx

I want to get the effect of "the wall", something like the walls of the maze.

```
    if(gameObject1.overlaps(gameObject2)){

    }
```

GameObject1 is moving and GameObject2 is to be wall. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Define both objects (moving and wall) as `Rectangle`s (or set of `Rectangle`s).
   Now you can use n^2 overlapping test on all of them.
2. You need to implement appropriate collision response once the collisions are detected.
   This would include disabling motion in that direction. You can do it using flags for each direction.

---

Alternatively, you could use a physics engine and let it handle the collision handling completely.